# Nginx's Location Not Grabbing Index Page

Tags: nginx

This code:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            limit_req zone=limit burst=5 nodelay;
            try_files $uri =404; 
            fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
            include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
            }
```

Works fine, if the .php is in the url. But if I am on my index (index.php) and there is NO '.php' in the address bar, the limit_req doesn't work.  Is there a away to catch all .php pages regardless of their extension? (Somehow, internally and not depending on the location function)?

Also, above my server block is:

```
index  index.php index.htm index.html;
```

As index.php is the ONLY page that isn't being catched by my above code.  All other .php pages are. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, pretty sure this is the solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/322018/nginx-not-executing-php-files Should of searched before making this topic, sorry.